# JSON posting undefined data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having problem in `JSON`.
Not good at `JSON` so i could not find whats the problem.
Here's the `JSP` code.

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){

        window.onload = dept_select;

        $("#sales_dept_id").change(dept_select);

        //alert("$("#sales_sabn_id").val() : "+$("#sales_sabn_id").val());
        //alert("!!");
    }
    );

var dept_select = function(){
var deptId =$("#sales_dept_id").val();
var sabnId =$("#sales_sabn_id").val();
alert(deptId);
alert("sabnId : "+sabnId);
$.ajax({ 
     type:"POST",
     url:"/servlet/servlet.json.JSonSalesSabnRequestServer", 
     data:{"sales_dept_id": deptId
          }, 
     dataType:"JSON", 
     success:function(jsonData){
        alert("jsonData : " +jsonData);
        //alert("jsonDatalength : " +Object.keys(jsonData).length);
         //var aa=JSON.parse(jsonData);
         //alert("aa : " +aa);
        //alert(jsonData[0].sales_sabn_id);

         var str = "<option value=''>SEL</option>"; 
         for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length;i++){
             if(sabnId == jsonData[i].sales_sabn_id){
                 str = str+"<option value='"+jsonData[i].sales_sabn_id+"' selected >"+ jsonData[i].sales_sabn_name+"</option>"; 
             }else{
                 str = str+"<option value='"+jsonData[i].sales_sabn_id+"'>"+ jsonData[i].sales_sabn_name+"</option>"; 
             }

         } 
         alert("str : " +str);
         $("#sales_sabn_id").empty().append(str); 
      }, 
      error:function(xhr, status, err){
         alert(status+", "+xhr.readyState+" "+err); 
      } 
   });
```

I can get

```
 'alert("jsonData : " +jsonData);'
```

It alerts.
But `jsonData.length` is too big and `jsonData[i].sales_sabn_id` is all undefined.
Pls help..

And here's the dataset

```
try {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        String sales_dept_id = StringUtil.getNullCheck((String)request.getParameter("sales_dept_id"));

        //FileUtil.writeLog("[JSonSalesSabnRequestServer.java] sales_dept_id = " + sales_dept_id);      

        DataUtil dataUtil = new DataUtil();
        ArrayList objList = dataUtil.getSaleSabn(sales_dept_id);

        for(int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++){
            JSONObject obj =new JSONObject();
            HashMap map = (HashMap)objList.get(i);
            FileUtil.writeLog("SABN : "+(String)map.get("SABN"));
            FileUtil.writeLog("SABN_NAME : "+(String)map.get("SABN_NAME"));
            obj.put("sales_sabn_id",map.get("SABN"));
            obj.put("sales_sabn_name",map.get("SABN_NAME"));
            objArry.add(obj);
        }

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");                               
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");                      
        response.getWriter().write( objArry.toString()  );

        FileUtil.writeLog("objArry.toString() : "+objArry.toString());

    }
```

Comment: Please provide the data formate of json

Comment: get me the output of this line console.log(typeof jsonData); put this in your sucess function and provide me the output

Comment: post the json response. Check if you json is valid http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: [{"sales_sabn_name":"a(1234567)","sales_sabn_id":"1234567"},{"sales_sabn_name":"b(1234568)","sales_sabn_id":"1234568"},{"sales_sabn_name":"c(1234569)","sales_sabn_id":"1234569"},{"sales_sabn_name":"d(1234560)","sales_sabn_id":"1234560"}]

Comment: The output is successable... but when i choose one of them, it comes undefined..

Comment: what's the typeof data in console ?

Comment: JSONArray objArry = new JSONArray();

Comment: not that i want output of `console.log(typeof jsonData);`

Comment: type is  It's string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is an array of objects. So you need to parse the JSON data if its a JSON string and then iterate it.

```
    $.ajax({ 
         type:"POST",
         url:"/servlet/servlet.json.JSonSalesSabnRequestServer", 
         data:{"sales_dept_id": deptId
              }, 
         dataType:"JSON", 
         success:function(jsonData){
            alert("jsonData : " +jsonData);

             var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(jsonData); // only if its a json string
             console.log(parsedJSON.length); // check length of the array

             var str = "<option value=''>SEL</option>"; 
             for(var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; i++ ){
                 console.log(parsedJSON[i].sales_sabn_id); // printing the id
                 if(sabnId == parsedJSON[i].sales_sabn_id){
                     str = str+"<option value='"+parsedJSON[i].sales_sabn_id+"' selected >"+ parsedJSON[i].sales_sabn_name+"</option>"; 
                 }else{
                     str = str+"<option value='"+parsedJSON[i].sales_sabn_id+"'>"+ parsedJSON[i].sales_sabn_name+"</option>"; 
                 }

             } 
             alert("str : " +str);
             $("#sales_sabn_id").empty().append(str); 
          }, 
          error:function(xhr, status, err){
             alert(status+", "+xhr.readyState+" "+err); 
          } 
       });
```